# How to find previous month in vb6 or in vba?

Tags: vba, vb6

i written a code in vb for finding the last month. but i didn't get the output which i am expecting.
here is my code:

```
a=Format$(Now, "mm")-1
```

but i want output in 2 digit like if last month is **Jan** then output should be **01** not only **1**

please help me out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the DateAdd function. More specifically:

```
date d = DateAdd("m", -1, Now)
a = Format(d, "mm")
```

Comment: It is "mm" if you want a leading zero, as per the original post.